# 'Functional' object has no attribute 'predict_classes' error when we use cross_val_predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, bert-language-model

I want to use Bert through Tensorflow.
**My plan is to use Bert with 5-fold cross validation, batch_size = 64, epoch = 100, and early stopping.**
I have 5 classes in my data.

Therefore, I wrote the following code (This code is an example to define my problem here):

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_text as text
...


bert_preprocess = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3")
bert_encoder = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/4")

def create_model():

  model = Sequential()
  text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
  preprocessed_text = bert_preprocess(text_input)
  outputs = bert_encoder(preprocessed_text)

  l = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1, name="dropout")(outputs['pooled_output'])
  l = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax', name="output")(l)

  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input], outputs = [l])


  model.summary()
  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
  return model

estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn = create_model,
                                  epochs=1,
                                  batch_size=64, 
                                  verbose=1
                                  )


kf = KFold(n_splits=5) 
pred = cross_val_predict(estimator, X_train, Y_train,
                          cv=kf,                          
                          verbose=1)
```

But I got the following error:

```
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
text (InputLayer)               [(None,)]            0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
keras_layer (KerasLayer)        {'input_type_ids': ( 0           text[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
keras_layer_1 (KerasLayer)      {'encoder_outputs':  109482241   keras_layer[12][0]               
                                                                 keras_layer[12][1]               
                                                                 keras_layer[12][2]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)               (None, 768)          0           keras_layer_1[12][13]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
output (Dense)                  (None, 5)            3845        dropout[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 109,486,086
Trainable params: 3,845
Non-trainable params: 109,482,241
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
38/38 [==============================] - 226s 6s/step - loss: 1.6111 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2434


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-55c3162a6b6d> in <module>()
     16                           
     17 
---> 18                           verbose=1)
     19 
     20 

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py in predict(self, x, **kwargs)
    239     """
    240     kwargs = self.filter_sk_params(Sequential.predict_classes, kwargs)
--> 241     classes = self.model.predict_classes(x, **kwargs)
    242     return self.classes_[classes]
    243 

AttributeError: 'Functional' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'
```

I also removed `model = Sequential()` but I still have the same problem.

How can I fix it? or
Is there any way to use all my plan?

Comment: Have you imported the cross_val_predict  `from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict` because some code lines are missing from your above code?

Comment: Yes, I have imported that but I didn't write the detail of my code here.

Comment: Can you please share the minimal reproducible code to replicate this error? Because predict_classes() is deprecated and replaced with predict().